# multiple sessions are created when inserting data into SQL table using ADF Pipeline through Copy Activity

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

i am using ADF Copy activity to move data from multiple Source SQL table into different Target SQL table. This is iterating parallel in loop using for each activity. but when it starts multiple sessions are generated (8-10 sessions) in the background for every copy activity. i am not using any parallelism/concurrent/bulk copy settings of copy Activity.
Please help me why this session is being created?

Comment: Have you checked Sequential in the ForEach Settings?

Comment: no i am copying data for all 10 tables in parallel  and sequential is unchecked. if i go through Sequential way it will time consuming

Comment: copying them in parallel is what causes the multiple sessions, each copy uses a session.

Comment: Is there any way apart from checking sequential ?

Comment: not that I am aware of but never dug into this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't select Sequential in ForEach, it will execute Copy activities inside ForEach parallelly at the same time like below.

[image]

Check the **Sequential in ForEach activity** as suggested by **@Scott Mildenberger**

[image]

Now, copy activities inside ForEach will be executed one after another in Sequential manner.

[image]

Comment: no i am copying data for all 10 tables in parallel and sequential is unchecked. if i go through Sequential way it will time consuming.
for each table copy 10 session is getting generated in SQL Background .

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
degree of parallelism was causing the issue where multiple instances where seen for the copy.
which means if we have 10 parallel copies and degree of parallelism is set to 5 then the instances starts in sql will be 10 X 5 = 50